# Resetting X position of image

Tags: c#, xna

I've written code to reset the x position of the ufo when it moves off the screen. I have taken into consideration everything that could happen with the ufo. 
Below is the code which says if the ufo travels off the screen, then the x position of the ufo is set back to 0, and it is killed off by means of false. I don't know what more i could add. The ufo travels off the screen, not to be seen ever again (poor thing) :( Any help?

```
   if (ufo.alive == false)
            {
                Random random = new Random();
                int randomNumber = random.Next(0, 100);

                {
                    if (randomNumber == 1)
                    {

                        ufo.alive = true;

                    }

                }
                {

                    if (ufo.XPos > 1000)
                    {
                        // kill the ufo if it goes off th 
                        ufo.alive = false;

                        ufo.XPos = 0;

                    }

                }

                //make a new one
                // here you want to do it randomly .
                // so
                //int random = random number (you have to do some code to make a random number google it.
                //if (random number == 1)
                // ufo = new ufo();
                // so if you tell it to make a random number between 1 and 1000, then every now and then, 1 will be the number it makes
                // fo when it amkes one, and randomnumber is equal to 1, it will make a new ufo.

                // i will let you figure out how to do the random bit.
                // i guess haha
            }
            //if ufo is alive
            // check for collision
            if (ufo.alive == true)
            {
                // also, we need to make it move
                ufo.XPos = ufo.XPos + 1;


                if (MissileFired != null)
                {
                    // if you miss, and the ufo carries on, it will go forever.
                    //so 

                    Rectangle rectMissile = new Rectangle((int)MissileFired.GetPosition().X, (int)MissileFired.GetPosition().Y, MissileImg.Width, MissileImg.Height);
                    Rectangle rectUFO = new Rectangle(ufo.XPos, 30, UFOImage.Width, UFOImage.Height);

                    if (rectMissile.Intersects(rectUFO))
                    {
                        PlayerScore = PlayerScore + 1000;
                        // we needed to kill the missile, other wise it gives you a point for every time it goes through.
                        MissileFired = null;
                        //now only 1000 points for winning
                        ExplosionSoundInstance.Play();
                        ufo.alive = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

EDITED CODE: above

Comment: Have you copied your code correctly? It looks as if you are missing at least one close-brace. For instance, at present the `if (ufo.alive == true)` is *inside* the block governed by `if (ufo.alive == false)`. Since you say your UFO moves off to the right, I'm guessing that the code you've actually run is different.

Answer (score 1):

the error you have is easy to debug and fix, you should learn to use a debugger, it is very useful.

here is [a debugging tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging)

Answer (score 1):

Basically the check to see if the position of the UFO > 1000 is never being run when the UFO is alive because it's inside the scope of the first IF statement.

```
if (ufo.alive == false)
{
    if (ufo.XPos > 1000)
    {
    }
}
```

if the UFO is moving shouldn't you be checking for the position while it's alive?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that your brackets are well-formed.  The open bracket { on line 5 doesn't make any sense there.  Plus you dont' have a closing bracket at the very end.

Maybe the code is dying not the UFO?